# Error: [$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.8/$injector/unpr?p0=NaNnvalidProvider%20%3C-%20%24invalid%20%3C-%20Ctrl

Tags: angularjs, error-handling, controllers

I have this code in the controller

```
app.controller('Ctrl', function($scope, $invalid, $location) {
$scope.upd_check = function()
    {
        console.log($scope.MyForm);
        if($scope.MyForm.$invalid){
            $("#modal_traffic_incorrect").modal('show');
        }

    }
```

My html code is

```
 <form name="MyForm">
          <div class="item_title">Text</div>
          <div class="item_contentbox">
            <input class="inputs len_md" name="number" ng-model="text" ng-required ng-pattern="/^([1-9])$/"   >

          </div><br />
<div class="col-md-offset-1 col-md-10 col-sm-12 text_right">
                <button type="submit" class="button" ng-click="upd_check()">Save</button><br><br><br>
          </div>
        </form>

        </div><br />
```

and I'm getting this error : Error: [$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.8/$injector/unpr?p0=NaNnvalidProvider%20%3C-%20%24invalid%20%3C-%20Ctrl

How can I suppose to fix that? Thanks for the help

Comment: where is your `MyForm` in html? Can also put html also? you should try `$valid` then `$invalid`

Comment: @ParthTrivedi I edited my question just now

Comment: try by remove `$invalid` from `Controller` and use `if(!$scope.MyForm.$invalid)`

Comment: You do not need to inject `$invalid` or `$valid`. Use it directly.

Comment: It shows the error TypeError: Cannot read property '$invalid' of undefined when I try that @ParthTrivedi

Comment: It shows the error TypeError: Cannot read property '$invalid' of undefined when I try that @ParthTrivedi

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103044/discussion-between-parth-trivedi-and-bleykfaust).

Answer (score 0):

[Error: $injector:unpr](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/unpr)

> This error results from the $injector being unable to resolve a required dependency. To fix this, make sure the dependency is defined and spelled correctly. For example:

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
.controller('MyController', ['myService', function (myService) {
// Do something with myService
}]);
```

The above code will fail with $injector:unpr if myService is not defined.

Making sure each dependency is defined will fix the problem, as noted below.

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
.service('myService', function () { /* ... */ })
.controller('MyController', ['myService', function (myService) {
// Do something with myService
}]);
```

so for your part, try:

```
app.controller('Ctrl', ['$scope','$invalid','$location',function($scope,$invalid, $location) 
{}];
```